# Подтверждение или отмена для button по id на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько кнопок:

```
<button id="49btn" class="b1" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator();">Start</button>
<button id="50btn" class="b1" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator();">Stop</button> 
<button id="51btn" class="b2" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator();">Test</button>
```

Есть JavaScript, который выводит предупреждение при нажатии на кнопку, если ОК - выполнить действие с кнопкой, если Отмена - не производить операции с нажатием кнопки:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#51btn").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'runner.php',
                data:{'51btn':'0'},
                success: function(data) {
                    $("p").html(data);
                }
            });
   });
});

function Validator(){
   if(confirm("Вы подтверждаете операцию?") ){
      document.getElementById('id').submit();
      return(true);
   }else{
      return(false);
   }
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы данное предупреждение работало для всех кнопок у которых указано значение id ? Т.е чтобы не писать функцию для каждой кнопки отдельно.
При нажатии КОНКРЕТНОЙ кнопки с таким-то id должно выдаваться предупреждение и если нажата ОК в предупреждении - то выполнить функцию Validator для конкретной кнопки (т.е сработать в итоге должна только кнопка, на которую нажали и в предупреждении нажали ОК)

Comment: Можно. А как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде можно вот так сделать ( передав id в функцию)

```
function Validator(id_){
   if(confirm("Вы подтверждаете операцию?") ){
      document.getElementById(id_).submit();
      return(true);
   }else{
      return(false);
   }
}
```

и

```
"JavaScript:return Validator(this.id);"
```

Пример( если подтверждаете то `alert` с `id` кнопки иначе `alert("2")`):

```js
function Validator(id_){
   if(confirm("Вы подтверждаете операцию?") ){
     var ttt= document.getElementById(id_);
     alert(ttt.id);
      return(true);
     
   }else{
     alert("2");
      return(false);
     
   }
}
```

```html
<button id="49btn" class="b1" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator(this.id);">Start</button>
<button id="50btn" class="b1" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator(this.id);">Stop</button> 
<button id="51btn" class="b2" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator(this.id);">Test</button>
```

Comment: А как при таком подходе выполнять далее $(document).ready(function()  ? Она должна выполняться после нажатия подтверждения.

Comment: Все разобрался. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать обработку события click для блока, в котором находятся кнопки. В этом случае при добавлении других кнопок не нужно будет писать обработчики для них.

```js
wrapper.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  //проверка ситуаций, когда id не заполнено, нет параметра id или клик идёт не на кнопку
  if (!event.target.id || event.target.id == '' || event.target.tagName != 'BUTTON') 
    return false;
  if (confirm("Вы подтверждаете операцию?")){
    alert (event.target.id);
  } else {
    alert ('Выполнение отменено');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <button id="49btn" class="b1" value="open">Start</button>
  <button id="" class="b1" value="open">Stop</button> 
  <button id="51btn" class="b2" value="open">Test</button>
  <div id='56btn'>Не кнопка</div>
</div>
```